# Why is the following estimation true?

Tags: prime-numbers, estimation, euler-product

> Why is the following estimation true ?
>
> $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{h_1,k_1\atop p|h_1k_1\implies p\le Y}\frac{e^{\Omega(h_1)}}{lcm(h_1,k_1)}\ll\prod\limits_{p\le Y}\left(1+\frac{1+2e}{p}\right)$
>
> , where $\Omega(h_1)$ is the number of prime factors (including repetition) of $h_1$

The original estimation below looks a bit different with exponent $\sigma_0\ge\frac12$ and Möbius-function, but this does not change much;

[image]

Comment: The notation is not clear, it does not seem like the product should even know what p is as written.